# KendoUI bootstrap 4 Angular 4: kendo UI are not rendered properly

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, bootstrap-4

I'm using VS2017's newest Angular4 template with ASP.NET core 2.0. This template is using bootstrap 3, I have replaced bootstrap now by bootstrap 4.0.0-beta, updated Popper.js to version 1.11.0 and jQuery version 3.2.1.

I have also applied the require(..) statements and plugin configuration in webpack as given in another article. If I launch the app, bootstrap is working, click events are working.

If I add a KendoUI button like below, I will get an error saying that property "[primary]" is an unknown property and the page cannot be displayed.

```html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<button kendoButton (click)="incrementCounter()" [primary]="true" >KendoUI button: Increment</button>
<button kendoButton (click)="decrementCounter()">KendoUI button: Decrement</button>
```

My project is available on github: https://github.com/palatineon/KendoAngular4Bootstrap4

Error message:

"An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

Decrement

NodeInvocationException: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'primary' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. ("ounter()">KendoUI button: Decrement-->

][primary]="true" >Increment

Comment: What purpose you want to achieve through primary attribute?